# Async workflows in F# - Execute in parallel and do not wait for the result

Tags: asynchronous, f#

Is it possible to use Async workflows in F#, execute multiple async operations in parallel but do not wait for the result ? Does it makes sense ? :)

So instead of this :

```
let runAll() =
    urlList
    |> Seq.map fetchAsync
    |> Async.Parallel 
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
    |> ignore
```

Do something like this :

```
let runAll() =
    urlList
    |> Seq.map fetchAsync
    |> Async.Parallel 
    |> ignore
```

Of course I need to start the the operation, so I tried just starting the execution of the async operation inside the fetchAsync function, it then works just by calling the function :

```
let runAll() =
    urlList
    |> Seq.map fetchAsync
    |> ignore
```

But then, my code is no longer parallelized :/

I may have missed something obvious.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is you want to start up a whole stack of Async operations but then do something else without waiting for them to complete.  In this case, you want to use [`Async.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353487.aspx) like this:

```
let runAll() =
    urlList
    |> List.map Async.Start
```

Comment: The code is still parallelized because you call `Async.Start` on every list element.  The penalty is you have no way of knowing when it is done